# Usage of "albeit"

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

Is it possible, in academic writing, to use the conjunction "albeit" exactly as one would use "although"? Except in academic writing, have you ever heard someone using this expression?

Furthermore, would this sentence be acceptable using "albeit" or "although", respectively?

(ps: An additional question of mine is whether "respectively" in my last sentence is correctly used or not).

> Many people feel uncomfortable about writing in books, *although / albeit* most academic books are not going to become valuable antiques in the future.

Comment: IMO, it is better to use "although". "Albeit" is more commonly used when the sentence after it is short. I went with my wife, albeit reluctantly. It is a wonderful jacket, albeit expensive. I took a part in that movie, albeit briefly.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the above sentence "albeit" is the wrong choice. "Albeit" is a formal word that fits better in formal or academic English though many people consider it archaic. Moreover, it should be followed by an adverbial or adjective phrase.
Examples:
1. He passed the exam, albeit with low marks.
2. They are still working for that company, albeit reluctantly.
3. The job I got, albeit rewarding,is so demanding.

So, you can use "albeit" exactly the same as "although" in the above or similar situations, but not with the sentence you mentioned where you use "although" as a subordinate conjunction followed by a dependent clause. So the difference is structural not semantic.

Answer (score 0):

"Albeit" generally stands for "although it is" or "despite its being", so it is not equivalent to "although". Albeit rare in casual speech, it can be useful and is sometimes heard from eloquent speakers.

In the example, "although" is a better choice.

"Respectively" is not required in the sentence in the way you used it. It is typically used to link one set of things with another set of the same number and order. For example:

> A, B, and Z are the first, second, and last letters in the English alphabet, respectively.